# Is there any restriction to transfer btc to another account?

Tags: php, bitcoin

I have account in [mkraken.com](http://mkraken.com) where my balance is around ฿0.05012, When I try to sent ฿0.00157 to other address using below code:

**Code :**

```
$res = $kraken->QueryPrivate('Withdraw', 
    array(
        'asset' => 'XXBT',
        'key' => 'Mykey',
        'amount'=> '0.00157'
    )
 );
```

Transaction will show in different state/status like initiated->onhold->cancelled.

I have check in panel where they said minimum transaction limit is 0.00100 and 0.00050 are the fee for transaction. so as per my code I have transfer more then that but still it'll give me transaction cancelled.

Any one having idea why transaction is failed...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got solution, Problem is not in code just you need to confirm your transaction with from your received mail.

When you sent request for withdraw mkraken team sent you email with confirmation link like R u sure you want to processed your transaction one's you confirm then and than it'll processed your transaction from **On Hold** status to **sending** status and **complete** your transaction.